# Strange texture shifting bug when using PointClamp or PointWrap

Tags: c#, floating-point, xna, textures, monogame

I am making a small RPG game and I'm currently on window rendering (things like inventory/quest windows).

I draw the actual window with 9 quads textured from a "skin", 4 corners, 4 borders and the middle.

The problem is, at arbitrary coordinates a triangle or two shifts slightly downwards.
It happens consistently, and only if PointClamp or PointWrap is used. Other opions work fine but they give a blurry look.

The same bug actually happens with the green bar above, however I "fixed" it by using Linear instead of Point.

I use this function to convert from pixel coordinates to screen coordinates:

**Note:** This function works as I originally expected in MonoGame.

```
    public static Vector3 PixelToScreen(GraphicsDevice device, float X, float Y)
    {
        float xscale = (float)device.Viewport.Width / 2;
        float yscale = (float)device.Viewport.Height / 2;
        return new Vector3(((int)X / xscale) - 1f, 1f - ((int)Y / yscale), 0);
    }
```

I suspect this function might be the source of my problem. Is there a "right way" to do it?

A picture is worth a thousand words, so here's a screenshot with the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNsnH.png

I am quite sure the solution is trivial, but I just can't catch it.

**UPDATE**

After some more digging and researching, I finally found a solution. It turns out that
it has something to do with how texture pixels are mapped to the screen pixels.

**UPDATE #2**

After porting this code to MonoGame, I've noticed a different bug where everything looks "blurry". Curiously enough, removing the offset (reverting to the original function) fixes the problem!

### The Fix

```
 public static Vector3 PixelToScreen(GraphicsDevice device, float X, float Y)
    {
        X -= 0.5f; // Offset the "pixel value" by half a pixel
        Y -= 0.5f; // To provide "expected results" use negative value
        float xscale = (float)device.Viewport.Width / 2;
        float yscale = (float)device.Viewport.Height / 2;
        return new Vector3((X / xscale) - 1f, 1f - (Y / yscale), 0);
    }
```

### More on the topic:

[Directly Mapping Texels to Pixels (Direct3D 9)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Understanding Half-Pixel and Half-Texel Offsets](http://drilian.com/2008/11/25/understanding-half-pixel-and-half-texel-offsets/)

This question is obviously resolved now, but I hope my findings will help someone stuck in the same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Fix

```
 public static Vector3 PixelToScreen(GraphicsDevice device, float X, float Y)
    {
        X -= 0.5f; // Offset the "pixel value" by half a pixel
        Y -= 0.5f; // To provide "expected results" use negative value
        float xscale = (float)device.Viewport.Width / 2;
        float yscale = (float)device.Viewport.Height / 2;
        return new Vector3((X / xscale) - 1f, 1f - (Y / yscale), 0);
    }
```

Do not use these offsets in MonoGame as it somehow takes care of the matters internally.